# Is it safe to mix green threads and native threads in a single python process?

Tags: python, multithreading, gevent, eventlet, green-threads

Firstly, is it safe to mix green threads such as eventlet or gevent with python native threads from the standard library, i.e. Lib/threading.py in the same python process?

Secondly, if it is safe, is it a bad idea?

Comment: If you are using green threads, why do you need a native thread?

Comment: because green threads still block on all syscalls except network IO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `gevent < 1.0` it is most likely a bad idea, as `libevent` isn't thread safe. You might be okay if you make sure that the OS threads never interact with `libevent`… But that could be tricky, and bugs cause by `libevent`'s lack of thread safety don't sound like any fun to debug.

However, `gevent >= 1.0` uses `libev`, which is entirely thread safe. So (as far as I can tell) there's no problem mixing green threads and OS threads.

Answer (score -2):

gevent provides [monkey patching abilities](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html#gevent.monkey.patch_thread) for threads.

Greenlets only switch to eachother within one thread, so one thread's greenlets will be completely separate and incommunicado from another's.

I wouldn't suggest using multiple threads of greenlets until you've shown you have a performance need to do so.

Comment: I think some explanation of why it's not a good idea is missing here.

Comment: @NiklasB. Maybe because multithreading is always a possible source for confusion and hard-to-track bugs. So if you don't get anything (or just very little) from multithreading, better avoid it.